# Llenar un array con VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Necesito llenar un array con datos que consulto de un api

este es mi array consultado

```
 getUsers() {
        this.$http.get("users").then(res => {
        this.users = res.data.data;
          });
  }
  }
```

Esto me devuelve mi peticion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero llenar otro array de acuerdo a los datos de mi petición, lo estoy intentando de esta forma

```
  getUsers() {
        this.$http.get("users").then(res => {
          this.users = res.data.data;
          for(var i = 0; i <= this.users.length; i++) {
              this.user[i].id = this.tableData[i].id
          }
          });
  }
  },
```

Esto me devuelve mi función

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haya quedado claro y me puedan colaborar con mi cosulta.

Comment: Para llenar un arreglo debes hacer `.push`, revisa esto:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push

Comment: Podrías indicar qué es lo que esperas obtener como resultado? Porque no me ha quedado claro cuando dices "Quiero llenar otro array de acuerdo a los datos de mi petición" a que te refieres con "llenar"? Quieres copiar los mismo datos?

Comment: Lo que hice fue consumir un api y guardar los datos en un array, quiero que estos datos traidos del array llenarlos con el otro, no se si me explique mejor, gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    
async getUsers() {
        try {
            await this.$http.get("users").then(res => {
                var objeto  = res.data.data;
                var data = [];
                var objeto = snapshot.val();
                for (var propiedad in objeto) {
                     data.unshift({
                     name: objeto[propiedad].name,
                     id: objeto[propiedad].id,           
                     phone_number: objeto[propiedad].phone_number,                                   
                });                  
            }          
        });
   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer], una edición explicando tu código siempre es bien recibida